# из combobox в массив

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, winforms, combobox

собственно, есть combobox1, заполненный некоторым кол-вом строк, как эти строки перенести в массив, или может быть проще как то к ним через индекс обращаться в цикле? суть в том что они по очереди заполняют на графике ось X, получилось заполнить график через DataBindXY, но он принимает массивы, вот и хочу через массив заполнить

Answer (score 2):

`сombobox1.Items` и так содержит массив значений. Зачем его куда-то переносить. Или можно через lambda выражения, если вам нужно его типизировать из `ObjectCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

[`ComboBox.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) содержит список всех значений в комбобоксе. Обратите внимание, что это свойство имеет тип [`ObjectCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), т.е. является нетипизированной коллекцией.

Проще всего получить массив из списка значений, используя LINQ. Например, если комбобокс заполнен числами:

```
var values = comboBox1.Items.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Если вы вдруг добавляете в комбобокс значения разных типов, то можете получить значения нужного типа:

```
var values = comboBox1.Items.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

Или же получить массив объектов:

```
var values = comboBox1.Items.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```